# strtok pointer takes delimeter value

Tags: c, strtok

I wanted to test strtok with multiple delimeters, and I wrote the code below, but after printing the first token, token takes the delimeter value instead that of the next word in the string.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char sent[]="-This is ?a sentence, with various symbols. I will use strtok to get;;; each word.";
    char *token;
    printf("%s\n",sent);
    token=strtok(sent," -.?;,");
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token=(NULL," -.?;,");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only call `strtok` once.

Comment: What is this -> ` token=(NULL," -.?;,");`

Comment: @ryyker That looks like a call to `strtok()`, without the `strtok` token. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intent is to call `strtok` in a loop, each time pulling the next token into a string, then change this line:

```
 token=(NULL," -.?;,");//this syntax results in token being pointed to
                       //each comma separated value within the
                       //parenthesis from left to right one at a time.
                       //The last value, in this case " -.?;,", is what
                       //token finally points to.
```

to

```
 token=strtok(NULL, " -.?;,");
```

Comment: ok that was a big mistake by my side, thank you for noticing, i waas going crazy!

Comment: @Erida.N - `token=(NULL," -.?;,");` is even more nefarious because it is a completely legal statement syntactically (and therefore may not flag a warning).  As is, it might even qualify for an honorable mention in a _obfuscated C_ contest :).

Answer (score 2):

You dont call strtok again in the loop:

```
token=(NULL," -.?;,");
```

this compiles because you use the comma operator here. The NULL expression is discarded and the expression yields " -.?;, and token points to that.

change it to

```
token=strtok(NULL," -.?;,");
```

Read more about comma operator here:

[What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)